# Understanding Assembly vs C counterpart

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, code-translation

Given this assembly code, I am having trouble translating assembly code into its equivalent C code.

[image]

```
   int main() {
      long int x=______;
      long int mask=0xff;
      int i,n,m;
      for(i=0;i<______;i++) {
         n=i;
         m=7-i;
         long int n8=n<<3;
         long int m8= m<<3;
         long int n_mask=mask<<n8;
         long int m_mask=mask<<m8;
         long int n_byte=((______>>n8) & ______;
         long int left_over = ______;
         x=left_over ______;
       }
    }
```

I was able to deduce some of the simpler blanks but am not sure how to figure out the rest.

Current Attempt:

```
   int main() {
      long int x=7;
      long int mask=0xff;
      int i,n,m;
      for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
         n=i;
         m=7-i;
         long int n8=n<<3;
         long int m8= m<<3;
         long int n_mask=mask<<n8;
         long int m_mask=mask<<m8;
         long int n_byte=((______>>n8) & ______;
         long int left_over = ______;
         x=left_over ______;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `n8=n<<3;` is being done with an LEA (with a scale factor of 8) to copy-and-shift.  Of course `n` is optimized away so it's just `n8 = i*8`, with no copying to a separate register to actually materialize an `n` variable before the shift.  Looks like it was compiled with `gcc -Og` or `gcc -O1`, because it didn't use the `xor %edx,%edx` peephole for setting EDX=0 before falling into the loop, instead using a mov-immediate of `$0`.

Comment: It is compiled with gcc -O1. Any idea what the rest of the blanks are?

Comment: Oh that's weird, I wonder what version of gcc would print `sarq %ecx, ...` instead of `%cl`?  x86 variable-count right shifts take the count in CL, not ECX.  (Not that it matters; they mask the count to only look at the low 5 or 6 bits anyway.)  But even the oldest gcc and clang on the Godbolt compiler explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/WMC9Ke) print the normal ` sarq  %cl, %rax`.  Either this is from an even older compiler, or it's hand-edited.  Anyway, looks like a mess of code to wade through, but I don't see any obvious problem with figuring out which variable is being shifted and masked.

Comment: Where are you stick?  Post a commented version of the asm with what you have so far labeling registers with C variables.  `x=left_over ______;` is weird, though.  I guess the previous line must declare and initialize it, because `left_over` doesn't appear anywhere else in the source, and that's the only place we can declare a new variable.  Presumably the last blank is an operator and some other variable.  Presumably `|` for the `or` instruction into RSI that's done last in the asm.

Comment: That is exactly particularly where I am stuck. I don't have much of an issue with the assembly commands themselves but having trouble figuring out what values are stored in which register so I can trace the commands.

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: I downvoted because your assembly code was posted as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

> having trouble figuring out what values are stored in which register so I can trace the commands.

Start outside the loop.

0xff = 255 so R9 is `mask`.

GCC hoists the `7` out of the loop, and does `7-i` with `mov %r10d, %edi` / `sub %edx, %edi`, so we know at that point m = EDI.  (And that `r10d` is just holding `7`, not `x`, because there's also a `movabs` to init another reg.)

The only other variable initialization outside the loop that's un-accounted for is `x`, so RSI = x.

It goes on from there.  From tracing `m`, it goes on from there.

Comment: For the first blank, I got (x & n_mask), the second I am not sure. The third I got x & ~m_mask and the fourth I got | (n_byte<<m8). Is this the right idea?

Comment: If you don't mind could you walk through the solution behind this so I can reason the logic?